# Update managed document without creating new version in MarkLogic 10

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-7, marklogic-10

I have one situation in which I am utilizing document DLS versioning feature in the application. So, there is demand of document updated before publishing a new version of the document (the reason behind is, it require verification from the third party before publish).
Below is the example for more clear idea,

```
/test/2c5faaaf-1f5f-4679-9918-0e8117a0ad7b.xml
/test/2c5faaaf-1f5f-4679-9918-0e8117a0ad7b_xml_versions/1-2c5faaaf-1f5f-4679-9918-0e8117a0ad7b.xml
/test/2c5faaaf-1f5f-4679-9918-0e8117a0ad7b_xml_versions/2-2c5faaaf-1f5f-4679-9918-0e8117a0ad7b.xml
```

In this example, I want to update some nodes in `/test/2c5faaaf-1f5f-4679-9918-0e8117a0ad7b.xml` (which is on the most recent version) and after the verification process, would like to create a new version (ie `3`) with changes made.

It works fine in `MarkLogic 7` with the help of `xdmp:document-insert` without losing the managed document from DLS collection and not working in `MarkLogic 10`

I am trying to achieve this situation because it is the demand for existing designed application which communicates with MarkLogic.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why that wouldn't still work. Post an example that demonstrates what is working in ML7 that doesn't work in ML10.

Comment: @wst `xdmp:document-insert('/test/2c5faaaf-1f5f-4679-9918-0e8117a0ad7b.xml', <some><xml>data</xml></some>)`
This works fine in MarkLogic 7 on managed document without losing the version history and not in MarkLogic 10.

Comment: @IAM What is the error you get on ML 10?

Comment: @RobS. when I try to update managed document using `xdmp:document-insert` it gets removed from the DLS managed document collection. This is the main issue which I am looking for a workaround. I need alternate to upate manged document.

Comment: @IAM The xdmp:document-insert command you shared doesn't include the collection so of course it is removed.Try passing it in as the 4th parameter.

Comment: You may need permissions beyond those of the user.
The DLS library 'amps' special permissions to allow managing the various internal collections and properties.

Comment: After more research found a solution to this. `xdmp:node-replace` never remove the managed document from the DLS collection. Thanks for your time to respond.